# Save video stream VLC

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, vlc, codec, video-recording

Given below is the code to stream data using vlc. I want to save the stream. Doing that using GUI is straightforward. How to do it using the C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ch=system("start C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc http://169.254.159.110/mjpg/1/video.mjpg --sout=\"#duplicate{dst=std{access=file,mux=ts,dst=stream.mp4},dst=display}");
}
```

I am able to record the stream now the only problem that remains is how to apply a codec to the saved video. Currently, 10 second video is taking about 1MB of space. I want to reduce that substantially.
What do I do?

Comment: I think that you try to record stream from vlc. See first some related questions, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633707/how-to-save-video-stream-using-vlc-in-commandline and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013503/capture-video-from-vlc-command-line-with-a-stop-time

Comment: @user1929959 I want to record the stream only. And I read that, based on the answer, trying to keep my command simple I tried to make the and its not working.

Comment: This is not really a C++ question, and it definitely isn't a C question.